# I am looking for a way to create a new list from a previouse one but only taking the words i want

Tags: python

So basically I am trying to make a new list from only the words that contain a certain keyword I want from a different list. I have the following.

```
desiredword = ['url']
```

Can anyone show me a way to use the desiredword list in order to extract the words that contain the variables within?

Comment: Provide a sample input and a sample output! Also provide what code have you written so fat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way is to use list comprehension because it provides a concise way to create new lists. A solution would look like this.

```
desiredwords = ['clone_url']
newlist = [ x for x in oldlist if any(word in x for word in desiredwords)]
print(newlist)
```